# Error on pod setup in new mac

Tags: ios, git, terminal, cocoapods

I am trying pod installation and pod setup in my new mac. But I got following issues on terminal. Anybody please could help me ?

```
 $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
  Cloning into 'master'...
  remote: Counting objects: 2131130, done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (503/503), done.    
 error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: do you have a slow internet connection?

Comment: This seems to have been answered here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7025

Comment: Reinier Melian  @ Yes, I do have slow connection. Does it matter much ?

Comment: evolutionxbox @ The problem is discussed but couldn't find the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do :-
1. It is related  to your connections.If your connection isn't proper then you can get this error.So, whenever it happens you should again try to follow the same procedure of installation.
2. I dont think this is a cocoapods library issue.

Try to clone repo manually https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs and then place it in ~/.cocoapods/repos/master