# Pods are not installing for Mac OS application

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoapods

I wanted to install some  pods on Mac osx application.
I gave this command: pod install

**[!] Unable to find a specification for `Alamofire`
You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.**

Then I tried this one as per suggestion:  pod update

**Updating local specs repositories
$ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/myName/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods fetch
origin --progress
remote: Enumerating objects: 4902319, done.

remote: Counting objects: 100% (2088/2088), done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1568/1568), done.

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly 516.57 MiB | 95.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `cocoapods` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`**

As suggested, I tried pod repo update --verbose command as well. this was the output:

**CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local
because checking is only perfomed in repo update
Updating spec repo `cocoapods`
$ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/zulqarnainnaveed/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods fetch
origin --progress
remote: Enumerating objects: 4902515, done.

remote: Counting objects: 100% (2284/2284), done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1761/1761), done.

error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `cocoapods` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:178:in `rescue in update_git_repo' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:169:in` update_git_repo'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:347:in `update' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:135:in` block (3 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:134:in` block (2 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `each' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in` block in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `open' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in` update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '**

I have tried multiple commands but nothing seems to work. I am using Mac 1 chip processor.

Comment: Have you tried as suggested: `pod repo update --verbose`, and wha's the output of that?

Comment: yes I have. I have added the output for this command in the question body again. You may check that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288558/error-on-pod-setup-in-new-mac ? Is your Web connection slow?

Comment: I do not think so. Because the problem occurs once the downloading is 100%. So probably it is not because of internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue.
I removed all the installed pods first. Then installed again.

Using this command

arch -x86_64 pod install

as I am using Mac M1. I have to install few pods for Firebase separately as well and a few in a whole with

pod 'Firebase'

pod command.